# Spacy NLP: For proper nouns that can be verbs - Ambiguities according to input order and split based on punctuation

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am using spacy NLP. No parser can always correctly determine the PROPN/ NOUN / VERB status of an ambiguous token, since in most languages a word spelt the same can have different meanings.

For example, "Encounter" can be an Encounter in terms of aliens zapping you into their spaceship(Noun, an occurence), or "Encounter" like "Encounter the world" --> Come into contact with (Verb).

Spacy sometimes identifies the same spelt-word differently, even in similar situations:
[image: Even with the same format of sentence, spacy changes how it identifies proper noun vs verb]

Is it the punctuation(the "="?) that causes this?

I expected continuity of identification of the token as either verb or noun, but not to change. I understand using the trained spacy data (using en_small and en_medium) does not use LSTM as it progresses so I should not expect spacy to "establish continuity due to a previous decision in the same sentence", but I am still surprised given the same sentence format, also identical content, spacy identifies differently..

Encounter the world. Encounter the self" and "Encounter the world=Encounter the self
=> 
parses to VERB, NOUN respectively

[image: Irregardless of punctuation used, Encounter is identified as "NOUN" in the second occurence, with the "world-then-self" order]

"Encounter the self. Encounter the world."

=> parses to VERB, VERB.

"Encounter the self"

=> parses to VERB

Comment: General advice: always segment your data properly. In this case, you clearly have two separate segments joined with a `=` char.

Comment: Have you tested by passing the two phrases separately?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew although not shown in the example figure, Spacy was separating this sentence into two spans automatically around the =. I added further examples to demonstrate the unexpected results

Comment: @TiagoDuque Thank you for advising - added further examples of entirely separate sentences.

Comment: I'm probably not mistaken if I say that 'self' is not being rendered as 'noun', right? I guess it's rendering it as a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using an up to date version of spacy and an up to date model such as en_core_web_lg .

On my setup, I do not get the error you are describing:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

doc = nlp("Encounter the world=Encounter the self.")
print([(t, t.pos_) for t in doc])
# [(Encounter, 'VERB'), (the, 'DET'), (world, 'NOUN'), (=, 'PUNCT'), (Encounter, 'VERB'), (the, 'DET'), (self, 'NOUN'), (., 'PUNCT')]
```

My version of spacy:

```
print(spacy.__version__)
# 2.2.1
```